# How I can fetch firebase database in this activity itself

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My code of Profile Activity How can I set this database in EditText and ImageView itself

for image:

```
mSetupImageBtn = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.setupImageBtn);
```

for name:

```
mNameField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.setupNameField);





 mStorageImage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile_Images");
    mDatabaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mSetupImageBtn = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.setupImageBtn);

    mNameField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.setupNameField);

    mSubmitBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setupSubmitBtn);


    mSubmitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startSetupAccount();
        }
    });

    mSetupImageBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
            galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            galleryIntent.setType("image/e");
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,GALLERY_REQUEST);
        }
    });

}

private void startSetupAccount() {

    final String name = mNameField.getText().toString().trim();

    final String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name) && mImageUri !=null){

        mProgress.setMessage(getString(R.string.fin));

        mProgress.show();

        StorageReference filepath = mStorageImage.child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

        filepath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")

                String downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();



                mDatabaseUsers.child(user_id).child("name").setValue(name);
                mDatabaseUsers.child(user_id).child("image").setValue(downloadUri);

                mProgress.dismiss();

                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
                finish();

            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

       mImageUri = data.getData();



        CropImage.activity(mImageUri)
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                .start(this);

    }

    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

            mSetupImageBtn.setImageURI(resultUri);

        }else if (resultCode==CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE){
            Exception error = result.getError();
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you want to retrieve data from the database? How are you retrieving?

Comment: What? In your code you added the name and then added it in the database. Then you retrieved the url from firebase storage and added it to the database and set it to the image `mSetupImageBtn.setImageURI(resultUri);` Why do you want to fetch them from the database if you already have them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the data:

```
 mDatabaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(user_id);
 mDatabaseUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  String names=dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
  String images=dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
   Glide.with(ActivityNameHere.this).load(images).into(mSetupImageBtn);
   mNameField.setText(names);
 }

 @Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {


 }
});
```

Use the `Glide` library to be able to load the image in the ImageView.